# Date in separate field

Tags: database, oracle

I'm pulling from a table in Oracle SQL developer that has fields: Id number, YEAR, DAY, and MONTH. The YEAR, DAY, MONTH fields are NUMBER data type.

I want to pull data from this table where the Year is between sysdate and 5 years ago. I'm having a problem with these fields being a number field and they are in separate columns. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE TO_NUMBER(YOUR_TABLE."YEAR")>=TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '5' YEAR, 'YYYY'));
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked:-) I didn't have TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bad design storing single components of a date in different columns (I fear you will notice problems quite soon).

Try this one:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(YEAR||'-'||MONTH||'-'||DAY 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -5*12) AND SYSDATE
```

Comment: Thank you. I agree. Unfortunately I didn't design it so i don't have permissions to modify it.